# How to get value from mssql DB in PHP

Tags: php, json, sql-server

Firstly I got the workers name from `BIRTHDAYS` and then want to get `e-mail address` from `USERS`.There is no problem to take workers name's from `Table1` but when I try to get the e-mail addresses the db returns me `NULL`.My DB is mssql.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$today = '05.07';
$today1 = $today . "%";
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM BIRTHDAYS WHERE BIRTH LIKE '$today1' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if($stmt == false){
    echo "failed";
}else{
   $dizi = array();
   while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
    $dizi[] = array('NAME' =>$rows['NAME']);
    $newarray = json_encode($dizi,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   }
 }

    foreach(json_decode($newarray) as $nameObj) 
{
    $nameArr = (array) $nameObj;
    $names = reset($nameArr);
    mb_convert_case($names, MB_CASE_UPPER, 'UTF-8');
    echo $sql2 = "SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '$names' ";
    echo "<br>";
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql2); 
        if($stmt2 == false)
        {
        echo "failed";
        }
        else
        {
        $dizi2 = array();   
        while($rows1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   
            $dizi1[] = array('EMAIL' =>$rows['EMAIL']);
            echo $newarray1 = json_encode($dizi1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }   
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual query you're executing?  Basically, what's the runtime value of `$sql2`?  When you execute that query against your database manually, what happens?

Comment: For example if BIRTHDAY table returns "David" I expected to return "david@abc.com" from USERS table.Because in USERS table "David" 's email is david@abc.com.

Comment: That's good, but what is *the actual query* that you're executing?  When you debug this (for example, you `echo` that value, so what *is* that value?) what *specifically* happens?

Comment: Why do you json_encode and then immediately json_decode afterwards in the same piece of code? Seems a bit of pointless overhead...since it's all happening in PHP you may as well just pass PHP variables around. The point of things like JSON and XML is to serialise data into text for transmission to another system or program which cannot directly read the variables in the current program.

Comment: Also, is querying on the names really very robust? It's pretty common to have more than one person called "David" for instance, so how are you going to tell them apart? Better to use an ID to match them, or something else which is generally unique to an individual, such as their email address. In other words, in the Birthdays table, don't store the user's name, store their ID, which is also present in the Users table. And create a foreign key relationship between them. That way you can also do this whole thing in one single query using an INNER JOIN.

Comment: SELECT NAME FROM BIRTHDAYS WHERE BIRTH LIKE '05.07' it return David
SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE NAME = 'DAVID' it return david@abc.com in db site but not in my PHP.Specifically nothing happens it just return [{"EMAIL":null}]

Comment: If you haven't studied database design, entity-relationships and normalisation, now would be a great time to learn. You'd be able to write, for example, `SELECT Email From Users INNER JOIN Birthdays on User.ID = Birthday.UserID WHERE Birth LIKE '05.07%'` and get the emails all of the users whose birthday matches the LIKE criteria

Comment: " it return david@abc.com in db site but not in my PHP"...so in that case there must be some difference. This clearly implies that in PHP you are either a) not in fact executing the same query (so please `echo` the finished SQL of your queries so you can check, as mentioned above), or b) not in fact connecting to the same copy of your database, where one contains different data to the other.

Comment: ADyson I know how to use INNER JOIN and I fixed my problem but I need to learn why it is return NULL

Comment: "I know how to use INNER JOIN"...so why didn't you do it?

Comment: "I fixed my problem" and "I need to learn why it is return NULL" contradict each other. If it's still NULL then you clearly haven't fixed it. For the `n`th time, carry out the debugging steps requested above to see what query you are _actually_ executing. Also check you're connected to the right database.

Comment: I just noticed...in `while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
    $dizi[] = array('NAME' =>$rows['NAME']);
    $newarray = json_encode($dizi,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   }`, you overwrite `$newarray` every time you loop. So if you have more than one user with that birthday, you'll only ever get the result of the last one the SQL returns. You don't need that construct anyway using the JSON as I mentioned. Just put everything with the initial `while` loop as per JayDee's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while($rows1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   
            $dizi1[] = array('EMAIL' =>$rows['EMAIL']);
            echo $newarray1 = json_encode($dizi1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
```

you put in $rows1 and would take it from $rows NULL is correct answer :)

take `$rows1['EMAIL']` and it would work

and why foreach =?

you can put the statement in while-loop like this:

```
  while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $names = $rows['NAME'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '$names' ";
    echo "<br>";
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
    if ($stmt2 == false) {
        echo "failed";
    } else {
        $dizi2 = array();
        while ($rows1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $dizi1[]        = array('EMAIL' => $rows1['EMAIL']);
            echo $newarray1 = json_encode($dizi1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @DarthMaul: The takeaway here is to use meaningful variable names.  "Rows" doesn't tell you anything about the data, all relational data is in rows.  And "Rows1" doesn't distinguish itself from "rows" in any meaningful way.  Names are important.  Use names that mean something and you'll be able to read your own code.